# Using a "declare" to define a s3 url to load in PIG

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I would like to use a declare to define a URL that will be used in several places in my PIG code, like this:

```
 %declare OUTPUT_S3_DIR s3n://mystuff/shouldgohere/
```

When I do that I get the following error:

ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 's3n://mystuff/shouldgohere/'

I have tried using all of these:

```
 %declare OUTPUT_S3_DIR s3n://mystuff/shouldgohere/
 %declare OUTPUT_S3_DIR s3n://mystuff/shouldgohere
 %declare OUTPUT_S3_DIR 's3n://mystuff/shouldgohere/'
 %declare OUTPUT_S3_DIR 's3n://mystuff/shouldgohere'
```

and it does not seem to work when I use it like so:

```
rmf '$OUTPUT_S3_DIR';
STORE my_data INTO '$OUTPUT_S3_DIR' USING PigStorage(',');
```

I am pretty frustrated with this since it is obviously a simple syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error I made was in the rmf command.
It needs to be

```
rmf $OUTPUT_S3_DIR;
```

and not

```
rmf '$OUTPUT_S3_DIR';
```

Hopefully someone else will not need to suffer...